# get correct headers with curl

Tags: php, curl, header

currently im using this code to get the headers:

```
get_headers( $url, 1 );
```

wondering how i can do with curl (more faster); this is my curl code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_exec($curl);
$info= curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

but i got "another" headers, i need the 'Location' header to see where go a bit.ly url or another redirect service.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the `Location` header, use this regex...

```
preg_match_all('/^Location: (?P<location>.*?)$/m', $headers, $matches);

var_dump($matches['location'][0]);
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/f0CQg).

If you want to stop cURL from following the `Location` header, check out [Charles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615361/get-correct-headers-with-curl/5615410#5615410).

Answer (score 1):

You want to turn the [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) is set to true.

edit:

Whoops, looks like you also need `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to get the content back from `curl_exec` and `CURLOPT_HEADER` to make sure headers are included in that.

Comment: Im looking to get the 'Location' and put into a variable, not follow the link, any idea?

Comment: Ah, I'd assumed you'd gotten that far.  I've updated my answer with the information needed.  Once you've gotten the response and headers, then you can parse it for the Location header, which is where @alex's answer is correct.